# Trying to load data from a binary file, results in FileNotFound but the file is located there if i search it in my windows search bar

Tags: java, binaryfiles, java-io

I've been working on a small little program for fun and now i have noticed that when i run it and it tries to load the data it will say 'The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect' However the location of the file is exactly the same

```
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
public static void loadData(String filename) {
    int accounts = 0;
    File f;
    try {
    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("./Clients/accountstorage.MKREAD");
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);

    String lineSep = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    String nextLine = "";

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("./Clients/" + "accountstorage.MKREAD"));
    while((nextLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        f = new File((String) ois.readObject());
        System.out.println(f.isDirectory() + " " + f.isFile()  + " " + f.exists());
        System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
        String path = f.getAbsolutePath();
        is = new FileInputStream(path.replace("\\.", "") + "/" + filename + ".ACC");
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);
        double bal = ois.readDouble();
        AccountState state = (AccountState) ois.readObject();
        String name = (String) ois.readObject();
        String lastname = (String) ois.readObject();
        int id = ois.readInt();
        Account accounte = new Account(id, name, lastname, bal, state);
        getStorage().addAccount(accounte);
        System.out.println("LOADED files");

        ois.close();
        is.close();
    }




    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        Alert("NOTE", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

this results in the following:

```
    java.io.FileNotFoundException  C:\Users\lucas\workspace\Dinges\Clients\Ouwens\Lucas
\BalanceInfo.ACC (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
      at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at dinges.Account.loadData(Account.java:158)
        at dinges.Main.main(Main.java:14)
```

However when i search it up in my windows bar `C:\Users\lucas\workspace\Dinges\Clients\Ouwens\Lucas` 
it shows up and the BalanceInfo.ACC is in there

But it doesn't find it when i try it with the program, what could be wrong? Is there a possible invalid character in it?

Answer (score 0):

Just use absolute file path. That would be the easier solution. For example I would write something like this:

```
String dirPath = "C:\Users\lucas\workspace\Dinges\Clients\Ouwens\Lucas\";
```

and pass it to whatever I am doing. Concatenating with my file name would be real easy.

If you are doing project that can be loaded on different computers, this method will not work but in that case, all you need to do is use this:

```
System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

It will give you the current directory you are working on. You can then use the slashes to go to where the file is saved.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that there is an invalid character somewhere in the filename.

Try replacing the line

```
   is = new FileInputStream(path.replace("\\.", "") + "/" + filename + ".ACC");
```

with

```
   String fullPath = path.replace("\\.", "") + "/" + filename + ".ACC";
   System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(fullPath.toCharArray()));
   is = new FileInputStream(fullPath);
```

The second of these three lines should print out the individual characters that make up the string in `fullPath`, with non-ASCII characters appearing as character escape sequences such as `\n` or `\u200b`.

Comment: It still gives the same error, infact now it's errorlined is = new FileInputStream(fullPath);

Comment: @LucasOuwens : I wouldn't expect the above change to your code to make it work.  You asked the question "Is there a possible invalid character in it?", and my answer helps you to find that out.  What did the line I added print out?

Comment: alright! Well, there's an unknown space that doesn't appear in the file itself so i will just rewrite the method